# Input.GetKeyDown() не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой. Я создавал оружие для персонажа, и решил назначить для этого клавишу, однако свойства, которые я ей задал не работали. Тогда я убрал почти всё и оставил только `Debug.Log()`, но всё равно ничего не происходит при нажатии на клавишу. Проблема возникает здесь:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
    {
        Debug.Log("x");
    }
}
```

С чем это может быть связано, и как это решить?

Comment: А не может быть клавиатура переключена на русский язык, или от этого не зависит? Ну и проблема может быть в другом вашем коде

Comment: Нет, клавиатура была с английской раскладкой.

Comment: посмотрите связали ли вы этот скрипт с объектом. пройдитесь по логической цепочке действий.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato благодарю, я применил его не к оружию, а к игроку, связав его с оружием через метод.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Я применил его не к оружию, а к игроку, связав его с оружием через метод.

Comment: И как этот ответ может помочь будущим посетителям?

Comment: @aepot Таким способом я решил свою проблему.